# Ibatis: Define a getter as a property on a result

Tags: java, sql, spring, ibatis

Can I define a getter as a property on a result in Ibatis?

like

```
    <resultMap id=.... class=...>
       <result property="getSomeValue" column="valueColumn"/>

....
```

I haven't seen this in documentation so far.

Comment: yep in the above example its just setting property="someValue" and if the getter exists it works :D (note there is no field named someValue on the bean I am using, Ibatis actually call my getSomeValue method instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the getter is

```
 public Value getSomeValue(){
        ...
    }
```

then the result would look like

```
 <result property="someValue" column="valueColumn"/>
```